Is a CC licence an appropriate licence for a programming language description?
I am a bit unsure but would expect, that in my case a CC BY-NC would be the thing I want.
What I am creating is an educative programming language for "offline" use, a learning game without a computer.
So, even if the language is a dialect of an existing programming language family it is not meant to become a piece of software running on a computer. It's environment is an "analog" implementation of it.
Am I right, that conclusively a software licence of any kind would be inappropriate in this case?

You haven't said what you are trying to allow with your work in precise enough terms. For example, if someone downloads your description from a website, what do you want to allow that she be able to do with that description? Is she allowed to package it into another package and distribute that, for example, as long as there's no fee attached? Is she allowed to make changes to it and redistribute the modified version of the description? And so on. Finally, what if someone does decide to make an executable version out of your description; do you want to allow that?

Thank you very much @Brandin. The final point is the crucial one. Earlier I thought about my idea as an implementation and I now think again, that this is more correct than thinking of it as another dialect. It happens in the Lisp spectrum and maybe the flexibilty of Lisp confused me here: Did I just add something to the language or did I change it? - However, parts of it certainly can be used for making executable versions. But even so, does ... ah, is in this case a combination appropriate: The natural text a CC licence and the part with source code a free software licence?

A programming language description is a document that describes which instructions a programming language understands and what syntactical format those instructions must take.
A programming language description is not software, so you are right to choose a non-software license for it.
In terms of copyright, a programming language description is completely independent from a program written in that language, or even a program designed to translate from the language to machine instructions.

Based on your proposal to use CC BY-NC, I assume you wish to block commercial redristribution of your application.  This is incompatible with any free software license.  Per help, I'm relying on https://opensource.org/osd, which requires Free Redistribution:  Any party can sell or give away the software.
Ignoring these concerns and asking whether CC licenses are appropriate in general for OPs purposes, I'll cite the official Creative Commons FAQ, which discusses the the reasons for preferring a software-focused license for software:

Unlike software-specific licenses, CC licenses do not contain specific terms about the distribution of source code, which is often important to ensuring the free reuse and modifiability of software. Many software licenses also address patent rights, which are important to software but may not be applicable to other copyrightable works. Additionally, our licenses are currently not compatible with the major software licenses, so it would be difficult to integrate CC-licensed work with other free software. Existing software licenses were designed specifically for use with software and offer a similar set of rights to the Creative Commons licenses.

In my opinion, the concerns described in the CC FAQ don't really apply to OP's "software":

The distribution of source code is probably is irrelevant, since OP's programming game doesn't have its own source code. It does have documentation, but CC's FAQ does mention that CC licenses are fine for "software" documentation.
Compatibilty with other licenses is probably irrelevant, since including OP's game in a software package probably doesn't make sense.

